# Remove duplicates based on combination of two columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I need to delete duplicated rows based on combination of two columns (person1 and person2 columns) which have strings.
For example person1: ryan and person2: delta or person 1: delta and person2: ryan is same and provides the same value in messages column. Need to drop one of these two rows. Return the non duplicated rows as well.

```
Code to recreate df 
df = pd.DataFrame({"": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     "person1": ["ryan", "delta", "delta", "delta","bravo","alpha","ryan"], 
                     "person2": ["delta", "ryan", "alpha", "bravo","delta","ryan","alpha"], 
                     "messages": [1, 1, 2, 3,3,9,9]})
```

```
 df
        person1 person2 messages
0   0   ryan    delta   1
1   1   delta   ryan    1
2   2   delta   alpha   2
3   3   delta   bravo   3
4   4   bravo   delta   3
5   5   alpha   ryan    9
6   6   ryan    alpha   9
```

Answer df should be:

```
 finaldf
        person1 person2 messages
0   0   ryan    delta   1
1   2   delta   alpha   2
2   3   delta   bravo   3
3   5   alpha   ryan    9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
res = (df[~df.filter(like='person').apply(frozenset, axis=1).duplicated()]
       .reset_index(drop=True))

print(res)

     person1 person2  messages
0  0    ryan   delta         1
1  2   delta   alpha         2
2  3   delta   bravo         3
3  5   alpha    ryan         9
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select just the columns with `person*`.
- For these columns only we use [`df.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to turn each row (`axis=1`) into a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). So, at this stage, we are looking at a `pd.Series` like this:

```
0     (ryan, delta)
1     (ryan, delta)
2    (alpha, delta)
3    (bravo, delta)
4    (bravo, delta)
5     (alpha, ryan)
6     (alpha, ryan)
dtype: object
```

- Now, we want to select the duplicate rows, using [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and add `~` as a prefix to the resulting boolean series to select the *inverse* from the original `df`.
- Finally, we reset the index with [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less general approach than the one given by @ouroboros1, this only works for your two columns case

```
#make a Series of strings of min of p1/p2 concat to max of p1/p2  
sorted_p1p2 = df[['person1','person2']].min(axis=1)+'_'+df[['person1','person2']].max(axis=1)

#subset to non-dup from the Series
dedup_df = df[~sorted_p1p2.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the two person columns in order within each row, then drop duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     "person1": ["ryan", "delta", "delta", "delta","bravo","alpha","ryan"],
                     "person2": ["delta", "ryan", "alpha", "bravo","delta","ryan","alpha"],
                     "messages": [1, 1, 2, 3,3,9,9]})

print(df)
swap = df['person1'] < df['person2']
df.loc[swap, ['person1', 'person2']] = df.loc[swap, ['person2', 'person1']].values

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['person1', 'person2'])

print(df)
```

After the swap:

```
     person1 person2  messages
0  0    ryan   delta         1
1  1    ryan   delta         1
2  2   delta   alpha         2
3  3   delta   bravo         3
4  4   delta   bravo         3
5  5    ryan   alpha         9
6  6    ryan   alpha         9
```

After dropping duplicates:

```
     person1 person2  messages
0  0    ryan   delta         1
2  2   delta   alpha         2
3  3   delta   bravo         3
5  5    ryan   alpha         9
```